# Is it possible to merge disjoint Git repos that were imported from the same CVS source?

Tags: git

I have a number of repos that are imports from CVS performed in the past by different individuals.

All of these repos have the same commit history matching what was in CVS and going back to the same initial commit in CVS but, although it's obvious the commits are the same,  there commit ids differ. Later commits diverge because different changes were made in each of them but their ancestory is identical and traces back to the same initial commit.

I've fetched all these repos into a single new one. Looking at the branches (with gitk) I can see they are all disjoint despite having the same change history.

What I'd like to do is somehow have git recognise the commits that are the same so the histories can be merged into a single tree. Is this possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, this is possible! And, as is usual for git, there are a few ways to do it.

What you want are **grafts** or **replacement refs**. Here's the replacement ref way first:

- Use `git replace` to replace all duplicated commits with their "canonical" versions. Pick one repository's version of a commit to be authoritative, and then repeatedly `git replace <other_repo_commit_hash> <primary_commit_hash>`. As you do this, the histories will become connected.

And here's the grafting way:

- Create a text file called `.git/info/grafts`. In there, each line should consist of a commit hash, then a space, then a whitespace-separate list of the parent(s) that commit should pretend to have. So if you have two "same" commits, A and A', and they have children B and C respectively, you would want to graft C onto A (giving A two children, B and C). You would do this by putting C's commit hash followed by A's onto a line in the graft file. When you do this, the repository will look like this:

  ```
        A ---- B
         \
          C
  ```
- Note that A' is gone. In sufficiently new versions of git, you can use `git replace --graft` to get graft-like functionality, although it will actually use replacement refs under the hood.

Once you are done grafting or creating replacement refs, you should have one connected history with everything in it. Now you want to run `git filter-branch -- --all` over it to make the substitutions permanent. You don't need to do any real rewriting, although you can if you want: just running the `filter-branch` will make the replacements/grafts go away and leave seamless history. Send the resulting unified branches (but not the old junk!) to a new git repo and you're done.

Comment: Thanks for this. I tried `replace` but it didn't do what I wanted. The `graft` option did, however, and very nicely too!" I used `.git/info/grafts` and then did `git filter-branch -- --all` (notice I needed two additional hyphens in there). I then did some clean-up which I'll explain in another answer.

Answer (score 3):

With gratitude to [@Borealid](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31582597) this is how to graft branches with the same history together. It works when the histories have different commit ids.

First, write entries to the file `.git/info/grafts`. Each line contains two commit refs `A` and `B` where `A` is the first commit in the branch to retain and `B` is its new parent. If, as in my case, each branch was being grafted to the same point, all entries have the same `B`. I had two such branches and my file looked like this:

```
209cbb0179ee490f4dbb7aaa6b7d7e32a1f4d21e 637bafd129d781516f9b1efbccd326484efecdb3
be007b20ac07770098701927730e01d965186b6e 637bafd129d781516f9b1efbccd326484efecdb3
```

Now, verify how it looks in `gitk --all`. If it was already running then hit `<SHIFT><F5>` to reload. Once you are happy that it looks as expected, proceed to make the changes permanent:

```
$ git filter-branch -- --all
$ rm .git/info/grafts
$ git for-each-ref --format="%(refname)" refs/original/ | xargs -n 1 git update-ref -d
$ git reflog expire --expire=now --all
$ git gc --prune=now
```

The last three commands come from the `git filter-branch` [documentation](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-filter-branch#_checklist_for_shrinking_a_repository)

Comment: Git version 2.39.1 informs me that:
Support for <GIT_DIR>/info/grafts is deprecated and will be removed in a future Git version.
Please use "git replace --convert-graft-file"
to convert the grafts into replace refs.